# How to properly create URL Masking for Cloud Functions to create a NEG?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, load-balancing, url-masking

I'm trying to protect my Firebase Cloud Functions with Cloud Armor so I'm trying to setup Load Balancer. I created a Backend and added a Serverless Network Endpoint Group. In this panel, I can select only one cloud function but I have more than one cloud function so I have to use other option which is URL masking.

I'm following this guide: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#using-url-mask

Problem is:

When I try URL masking like this:

```
us-central1-myproject-a123b.cloudfunctions.net/<function>
```

It doesn't work like this. I've readed official guides about NEG and URL masking but I really don't understand how can I create a serverless network endpoint group containing all my cloud functions with an URL containing `<function>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the documentation, if the pattern is `<your function URL>/<functionName>` (that is your case `us-central1-myproject-a123b.cloudfunctions.net/<function>`), you have to set `/<function>` in the url mask